# SKTexture textureWithImageNamed using too much memory

Tags: cocoa, memory, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, sktexture

I'm trying to make a kind of 360° visualizer with spriteKit. In my scene i create a

```
spriteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and i'm filling it in this way:

```
for ( int j=0; j<stepsY+1; j++)
{
    NSMutableArray * innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for ( int i=0; i<stepsX+1; i++) {
        SKTexture *t = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_0_%d_%d.jpg", (stepsY-j),(stepsX-i)]];
        [innerArray addObject:t];
    }

    [spriteArray addObject:innerArray];
}
```

for example i will have a two dimensional array 4x23; with four steps for y axis and 23 step for x axis; on

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

i'm using

```
[sprite setTexture:....];
```

to set the right texture to visualize;

When i'm running it on the simulator it works perfectly but when i try on the real device, when i'm filling the spriteArray the app crashes and xcode is telling me "Terminated due to Memory Error";
So i checked the use of ram in simulator and i recognize that is huge... 1.5gb; my texture are 1220x1220 jpg each one around 50kb.... so it's seems that there is a kind of memory leak somewhere.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not a memory leak, just a misconception: file size has **nothing to do** with texture memory usage.

1220x1220 amounts to 1,488,400 pixels. By default textures use 32 bits per color (4 bytes). This gives you about 5.7 MB memory usage per texture.

4 times 23 is 92.

92 times 5.7 MB gives you a memory usage of well over 500 Megabytes.

Furhtermore, if Sprite Kit internally uses only textures with dimensions that are multiples of 2 then the real texture size would be 2048x2048 (16 MB per texture) and a total texture memory usage of nearly exactly 1.5 Gigabytes.

Well, there's your problem. :)